# what is the format of program.cs in a blazor application

Tags: c#, blazor

I am just started to learn Blazor and created a sample blazor application in VS .

Looking at the generated code, I noted that file program.cs is not a class or method, as it contains the following code:

```
using BlazingPizza.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
// Register the pizzas service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PizzaService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PizzaStoreContext>();
    if (db.Database.EnsureCreated())
    {
        SeedData.Initialize(db);
    }
}

app.Run();
```

The code in this file seems more like a script than a class, method or similar construct in C#.

What is the format of this file? Where is the main function and how the main function related to this code/file?

## Edit 1

the difference between my question and the question that was highlighted as duplicate is that I did NOt know this new feature in C#9 and if I know about it, then I could find more information about it in Microsoft Docs or online.

The duplicate question is about this new feature and if you are not familiar with it, you would not search for it and never come to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new feature in C# 9, called [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).

You can basically have one .cs file per project with top-level statements, that replaces the main method.